# Magento Add to Wishlist button not working

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, magento, button

I needed to make the wishlist link a button so i changed the code in addTo.phtml from

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>

<button type="button" class="button fabriqButton2"><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;"><span><span><?php echo __('Add to Wishlist');?></span></span></a></button>
```

For some reason this works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.
Does anybody know a way to get this to work as a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid the use of an `<a>` tag inside the `<button>` tag. Instead move everything to the onclick of the button and remove the `<a>` tag.

```
<button type="button" class="button fabriqButton2" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, '<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>');"><span><span><?php echo __('Add to Wishlist');?></span></span></button>
```

And your second question:

```
<button type="button" class="button backLink fabriqButton" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>');"><span><span><?php echo __('Back');?></span></span></button>
```

**NOTE**
setLocation is a custom method from Magento. If you would need this for other projects you would most likely use `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/'`

Comment: Ah thank you for the reply:)
I figured that this was invalid. But i don't know how to move everything to the onclick of the button. How would i send the 'href' attribute in there too?

Comment: I edited my post above, the href attribute was only there as a fallback in case JavaScript breaks, I got rid of it and only put the `productAddToCartForm.submitLight()` in there.

Comment: @Weszzz7 Correction, it actually said `productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href);` so I put the old href attribute instead of `this.href`. Try the code and see if it works ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, couldn't figure it out without removing the button :)

Comment: Ej Rick,

Do you know a fix for the following too?

    <button type="button" class="button backLink fabriqButton" onclick="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><span><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Back');?>"><?php echo __('Back');?></a></span></span></button>